# Continuity and Differentiation on a interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x\sin(1/x), & \text{if $x$ $\ne$ $0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x$ = $0$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Is $f$ continuous on $(-1/\pi$, 1/$\pi$)?
Is $f$ differentiable on $(-1/\pi$, 1/$\pi$)?

I have a question with this problem. I know how to prove continuity on a single point, bu I'm not sure how to prove continuity for a whole interval. Also, I know there is a theorem that states that if a function is differentiable at a point, then it's continuous but I have a feeling that $f(x)$ is continuous but not differentiable.

Comment: To prove continuity in internal go for critical point at x =0 because at other places function is xsin(1/x) which is continuous as it is product of two continuous function

Comment: I remember this function when I was in High School, my professor gave this an example of function which is continuous but not differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

To check continuity at $x=0$ use the squeeze lemma: clearly $ -1< \sin x < 1 \ \forall x$, so $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) =0 = f(x_0)$, so the function is continuous. To check differentiability use the definition: $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$. what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

By first principles $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\sin(1/h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\sin(1/h)$

Which is undefined, so yes it is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your feeling is true. To check $f$ is continuous  on$(-1/\pi,1/\pi)$, you only need to check $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$. This can be proved using [Squeeze_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

For the undifferentiability, prove that
$$
f^\prime(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\sin(1/h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\sin(1/h)
$$
doesn't exist.